# Absolute and Relative Coroots

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, root-systems

$G$ is a connected reductive group over a field $k$. $T$ is a maximal torus and $S \subset T$ is a maximal $k$-split torus. We have an embedding $X_*(S) \hookrightarrow X_*(T)$. Is it true that  if $\alpha \in X_*(S)$ is a linear combination of absolute coroots in $X_*(T)$ then $\alpha$ is a linear combination of relative coroots in X_*(S)? How could one prove this?

Comment: What if $S$ is central in $G$, so that there are no relative coroots?

Comment: Is this still an issue if I assume $G$ is quasisplit? I'm happy to assume that.

Comment: Are you assuming $S$ is maximal as a split $k$-torus in $G$ (not just the maximal split $k$-subtorus of $T$)?  As you must know, one can't first pick $T$ and then expect to find an maximal split $S \subset G$ inside $G$, so really one should first pick $S$ and then choose $T \supset S$.  Is that what you mean? And can you say something about the motivation (e.g., to clarify why quasi-split $G$ is sufficient for your purpose, whatever it may be)?

Comment: Yeah, sorry this is what I mean, thanks.

Comment: I think what I really would like to show is that for $G$ a quasisplit connected reductive group, if we write  $\pi_1(G)$ defined by $X_*(T) / \langle \mathrm{coroots} \rangle$, $\Gamma= \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$, then $\pi_1(G)^{\Gamma}$ is isomorphic to $X_*(T)^{\Gamma} / \langle \mathrm{relative coroots} \rangle $

Comment: I think this is implied by my question.